# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found

Tags: craft-pro

I am developing my Craft site locally with MAMP. Today when starting my site on localhost, I got this error:

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'craft_mysite.craft_info' doesn't exist

I have replaced the /app folder with a fresh copy, but it didn't help.

Also, I can no longer log into my site: When navigating to my login page, I get the same error as mentioned above.

I have a recent database backup in /craft/storage/backups. Is there a way to get my site up and running again?

Comment: Sorry for asking the obvious, but if you connect to your `craft_mysite` database, does the `craft_info` table exist?

Comment: Hi Brad. I checked inside my phpMyAdmin and I haven't found any such table.

Comment: Well, there's the problem. :)  Have you been through the Craft installer yet? Do any other tables exist in the `craft_mysite` database?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by setting up a new installation and then importing my backup database into that new installation. Now everything is there again and works.

I must admit I haven't found the reason why this problem occurred. But the solution was ultimately quick and easy.